# How to remove all ip value with Notepad++

Tags: ip, notepad++, regex

I have a large text file that containing words like this:

```
12.0.84.130|test|test|United States (US)
12.0.84.131
12.0.84.132
```

Means some line with ip and text and some with only ip so i wanted to remove all the IP from the text file and want to make them like this:

```
12.0.84.130|test|test|United States (US)
```

So how can i do this in Notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you use search and replace, and tick the regex box, and look for a regex for finding IPs. e.g. `(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}`  put it in the find section and put nothing in the replace section.

If you want something that limits each octet to 0-255 then the regex would be a bit more complex, but you can google for regexes that identify IPs, but you may find that one I gave you is fine.  It looks for the pattern of between one and 3 digits, followed by a dot, let's call that pattern blah that's `(\d{1,3}\.)`.it looks for that to occur 3 times `(\d{1,3}\.){3}`, followed then by one to three digits `\d{1,3}`, giving the regex of `(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}` but regexes are a subject in themselves as you can imagine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with barlop,

but to remove only complete lines with a single ip in it
and leave those with text following like your example:

Find what: `^(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\r?\n`
Uncheck all boxes
Select Radiobutton Regular expression

Comment: I like the use of '?' in \r?\n to cater for windows or *nix in that regard,but still, perhaps '$' (that's the end of line equivalent to the ^ that marks beginning of line), $ might be better than \r?\n  since in Windows, \r\n is not a line terminator, it's a line separator, so for example if you open notepad and you type 'a' (without quotes),and don't hit enter, and then save it,  the file will be 1 byte, i.e. no \r\n after the line. So in windows \r\n means "new line". as opposed to *nix where \n means "end of the line" and so it is only with *nix that every line would have one.So eg  ^blah$

Comment: @Barlop I tested with `$` and then it gets no match, also if I understand right the whole line should be dropped so the line break has to be part of the match. Maybe a `\s*` in front and end could extend this a bit. But as your answer was accepted, Vicky seems to be happy with it.